# jasmine print getText output outside function

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, protractor

I am writing a protractor spec which uses angularJS and jasmine to get text from a page which I later want to convert from a string to integer. My first problem is accessing the getText value outside of the function. For example in the code below:

```
var post_count = element.all(by.binding('InboxItem.Count')).get(0);
 post_count.getText().then (function (text){
 console.log('mytext_inside_function = ' + text);
 return text;
});
console.log('mytext_outside_function = ' + post_count);
```

I can see that the code is executing asynchronously and the console.log my text_outside_function is running before the my_text_inside_function and thusly returning "object object" instead of the number 7( which is text and not a number)

```
ᐅ protractor protractor.conf.js --suite inbox
[10:56:34] I/local - Starting selenium standalone server...
[10:56:35] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver  
Started
mytext_outside_function = [object Object]
mytext_inside_function = 7
.
1 spec, 0 failures
Finished in 0.938 seconds
```

I am a new to jasmine promises and not sure how to correct this. I added the .then (function... to my test, but didn't seem to resolve the promise. 
My ultimate goal is to get the text ( 7) and then convert it from the current string to a number so I can do a calculation(addition) to it.

EDIT....
Thanks for the suggestion Nick. I guess I am doing this wrong. I added the mytext variable which I am thinking is outside the function( probably am wrong). see below..

```
 var post_count = element.all(by.binding('InboxItem.Count')).get(0);
 var mytext = post_count.getText().then (function (text){
 console.log('mytext_inside_function = ' + text);
 return text;
 });
 console.log('mytext_outside_function = ' + my text);
```

I get this error.

```
mytext_outside_function = ManagedPromise::810 {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending"}
```

Comment: Initialize a variable outside of the function and store the result in that variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either call `console.log` in the resolution of the `Promise` :

```
var result = element(by.binding('InboxItem.Count')).getText().then(parseFloat);

result.then((value) => console.log("count: ", value));
```

Or push a new function in the execution flow to display the result:

```
var count = 0;
element(by.binding('InboxItem.Count')).getText().then((text) => {
  count = parseFloat(text);
});

browser.controlFlow().execute(() => {
  console.log("count: ", count);
});
```

Comment: Florent, thanks your first suggestion worked! Thanks everyone!!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```js
const defer = Promise.defer();
var count =0;

var post_count = element.all(by.binding('InboxItem.Count')).get(0);
 post_count.getText().then (function (text){
   count = parseInt(text);
   console.log('mytext_inside_function = ' + count);
   defer.resolve(count);
   return defer.promise;
});


console.log('mytext_outside_function = ' + count);
```

Usually the second console.log line gets executed before the above promise is resolved. So you will see the console output as promise pending. You can use const defer = Promise.defer(); defer.resolve(count); return defer.promise; in the above function. By doing this you are waiting until the promise is resolved

Comment: Varun your answer gives me "mytext_outside_function = undefined"

Comment: sorry you need to do var count =0; in the first line or you can just use let count;

Comment: Varun, could you show your suggestion with the Promise.defer() as a code example?  I am curious how this works.